# how to create a chat input box in bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to create somthing that in bootsrap:

[colorpicker | input box | button] [toggle button]

[image: Chat inout box]

I have used:

```
        <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control">                  
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Send</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default">Users</button>
              </span>
            </div>
```

However, I don't know what colorPicker for bootstrap I should use (only 9 colors pickers) and how to add it on left side.

Any help is welcome.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5B5v5/

Comment: I don't think bootstrap has a way for you to add that color picker, but you could make something custom to place it inside a bootstrap input field. Show us a fiddle and it's easier to help.

Comment: fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5B5v5/

Answer (score 1):

Since I think you're saying you want a color picker with just 9 color options, I would go with a dropdown instead of a fully baked color-picker plugin... like so:

```
<div class="form-inline">
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
<!-- COLOR PICKER -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Color <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><a href="#"><span style="color:cyan" class="glyphicon glyphicon-tint"></span> Cyan</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span style="color:blue" class="glyphicon glyphicon-tint"></span> Blue</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span style="color:magenta" class="glyphicon glyphicon-tint"></span> Magenta</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">...more...</a></li>
        </ul>
<!-- END COLOR PICKER -->
      </div><!-- /btn-group -->
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Send</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**DEMO: http://www.bootply.com/ecziRvg9Jg**

If you *do* find a true color picker that lets you do 9 colors only, attach it to the button I commented in the code.